# TSQL CASE LTRIM (RTRIM NULL

Tags: sql, null, case

SQL Syntax is still something I am learning. I am getting the error noted below the this snippet of code.

```
SELECT
 CASE  WHEN    LTRIM(RTRIM(cLehmanNo)) =' ' THEN NULL 
       WHEN cLehmanNo IS NOT NULL  THEN REPLACE ( cLehmanNo,SUBSTRING (cLehmanNo,PATINDEX( '%[^a-zA-Z0-9 '''''']%',cLehmanNo),1), ' ' )
 END asLOAN_NUMBER
,CASE  WHEN    LTRIM(RTRIM(cMERS)) =' ' THEN NULL 
       WHEN cMERS IS NOT NULL  THEN REPLACE ( cMERS,SUBSTRING (cMERS,PATINDEX( '%[^a-zA-Z0-9 '''''']%',cMERS),1), ' ' )
 END asMERS_ID
```

and 100+ more of same.

```
Msg 8133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
None of the result expressions in a CASE specification can be NULL.
```

What am I doing wrong?  How do I keep the gist of the statement and not get this crazy error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when  it can't infer the type.

e.g.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN NULL ELSE NULL END
```

But this works

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN NULL ELSE replace(NULL,'','') END
```

so I doubt the error is from the code you have shown us (You are using string functions and the following quick test shows that it will assume that to be `varchar(8000)`)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN NULL ELSE REPLACE(NULL,'','') END a
INTO t /*Creates column of datatype varchar(8000)*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert NULL to a correct type matching the overall values, e.g. CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), NULL), otherwise the server can't deduce which type to make the resulting value.

Comment: or CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10));

Comment: Ah, okay I understand. I tried a couple of other things and found that this works:  CASE  WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(cLehmanNo)) ='' THEN NULL WHEN cLehmanNo IS NOT NULL THEN REPLACE ( cLehmanNo,SUBSTRING (cLehmanNo,PATINDEX( ' %[^a-zA-Z0-9 '''''']%' ,cLehmanNo),1), ' ' )END as LOAN_NUMBER (had to remove an additional Space on ' ' after the = sign. Then I had found later in the code where I had to add THEN REPLACE(Null,'','') prior END as in the following: ,CASE  WHEN    LTRIM(RTRIM(dtMicIssue)) ='' THEN NULL WHEN cMICNumber IS NOT NULL  THEN REPLACE (NULL, '', '') END as MIP_CERTIFICATION_DATE
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

The error message actually means that all results in one of your `case` expressions are `null`. You have an expression like:

```
case when something then null when something then null end
```

At least one of the results has to be something other than `null`. You could circumvent this, but most likely there is a mistake in the query, as a `case` exression that always returns the same result is pointless.

The error message [has been changed](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/301695/misleading-error-message-on-case-expression-with-untyped-null-in-each-result-expression) to:

> At least one of the result expressions
>   in a CASE specification must be an
>   expression other than the NULL
>   constant.

Comment: +1 I think there must be a mistake in the query as well if all parts return the NULL constant.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 CASE  WHEN    LTRIM(RTRIM(cLehmanNo)) =' ' THEN NULL 
       WHEN cLehmanNo IS NOT NULL  THEN REPLACE ( cLehmanNo,SUBSTRING (cLehmanNo,PATINDEX( '%[^a-zA-Z0-9 '''''']%',cLehmanNo),1), ' ' )

ELSE ''

 END asLOAN_NUMBER
,CASE  WHEN    LTRIM(RTRIM(cMERS)) =' ' THEN NULL 
       WHEN cMERS IS NOT NULL  THEN REPLACE ( cMERS,SUBSTRING (cMERS,PATINDEX( '%[^a-zA-Z0-9 '''''']%',cMERS),1), ' ' )

ELSE ''

 END asMERS_ID
```

Comment: Adding Else '' won't make any difference I think. This doesn't raise the error `SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN NULL WHEN 2 = 3 THEN REPLACE(NULL,'','') END`